# Getting NLTK running w/NumPY and matplotlib on OS 10.8

Tags: python, numpy, nltk

Just to be honest at the beginning here: I have no experience installing Python and its various modules.  I am trying to work through *Natural Language Processing with Python* to learn a bit about how programming can be used in linguistic research.

Apparently my Mac had one version of Python installed already.  In order to take advantage of all the examples in the book I need to get the Numpy and matplotlib modules working.  After a bit of trial and error was I able to install Numpy (and import it successfully when using Python in the terminal).  Then I tried to install matplotlib and wasn't able to.  The installation program said that you can't use matplotlib with the version of Python that came pre-installed by Apple.

So I've downloaded another copy of Python 2.7.5 and installed it.  Once that installation was on my system, the matplotlib installation went through.  But now I don't know how to install Numpy a second time (this time alongside the new Python installation), and matplotlib won't work with the new Python, even though it's been installed, because it appears to be looking for Numpy and not finding it.

I also have no idea which installation is now being used when I type "python" into my terminal.  But Numpy isn't importing there either, even though it did before I got into this mess.

I'm sorry that this is so jumbled; I hope it makes sense.  I just want to get the environment up and running and, preferably, know what all I have installed on my system and where it's installed.  Can anyone maybe point me on the right direction on what I should do next?  Is there a simple way to start from scratch with a user-installed version of Python and instructions on how to make sure I'm installing all modules to that installation?

Comment: [These instructions](http://penandpants.com/2012/02/24/install-python/) have worked for me on several different Macs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I followed the instructions, got this at the end of scipy installation: "1 error generated.
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd"

There's more but it's too many characters to include here.

I then got the same error when running "pip install matplotlib," except this time 67 errors were generated instead of just 1 with pysci.  I'll copy some of the text in another comment below...

Comment: clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'

clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/X11/include -I/opt/local/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include

Comment: Also, when I run Python from the terminal now, I can run "import numpy" and "import matplotlib" with no errors, but when I try to do a dispersion plot like the one in the first chapter of the book, I still get this error:

Comment: text4.dispersion_plot("independence")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/text.py", line 456, in dispersion_plot
    dispersion_plot(self, words)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/draw/dispersion.py", line 27, in dispersion_plot
    raise ValueError('The plot function requires the matplotlib package (aka pylab).'
ValueError: The plot function requires the matplotlib package (aka pylab)

Comment: It looks like it might want this style of matplotlib import: ``from matplotlib.pylab import *``

Comment: I used the instructions on the first website you showed me to install the Anaconda version of Python, which has all the modules already.  That seemed to work okay, so then I re-installed nltk for that Anaconda installation (though this time it required me to install something called X11, which I hadn't had to do when installing nltk before).  

Anyway, I'm no longer getting the error that matplotlib is missing.  Now, when I try to run the .dispersion_plot example from chap 1 of the book, I get no return at all.  No error, no new terminal line, just a blinking cursor.

Comment: I've tried the above with normal "import matplotlib" and "from matplotlib import *".  Here is my terminal:

>>> import numpy
>>> from matplotlib import *
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.book import *
*** Introductory Examples for the NLTK Book ***
Loading text1, ..., text9 and sent1, ..., sent9
Type the name of the text or sentence to view it.
Type: 'texts()' or 'sents()' to list the materials.
text1..text9
>>> text4.dispersion_plot(["citizens", "democracy", "freedom", "duties", "America"]).

After that, just a blinking cursor.

Comment: ``show()``, or better yet use ``ion()`` turn turn on interactive plotting before the run that ``plot`` command. Look into ``ipython``, and start it using ``ipython --pylab``, a mode which makes all these things just work the way you'd want.

Comment: What do you mean?  Just type show() or ion() at the Python prompt?  Those give me Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ion' is not defined

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31879/discussion-between-user1066615-and-dan-allan)

Comment: Hmm. That is what I meant. I don't think this is an installation issue anymore. I suggest you open a new question.

Comment: Opened a chat.  iPython works fine and regular interpreter seems to just be not bringing up the window even though interpreter thinks it's there (the blinking cursor is it waiting for me to close the plot window)